# Tabbar not showing when app is built after login. Only once I log out and back in

Tags: tabbar

When I build the project and click login. My first view opens but the tabbar is not showing. However only when i log out and log back in it shows. Im not sure if it is not being loaded or yet or something.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

[Parse setApplicationId:@"wcxqk8AoeQQPHWHdF1UJG0bqq8Plk6LuYLx2UuFX"
              clientKey:@"GPuouYfJOMCxMYpQbdb2Eh1sRgvYbdnQav1vQyQT"];
[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];


if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.106 green:0.588 blue:0.98 alpha:1]];
    NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                           shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,
                                                           [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold    " size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

}
else
{


}

[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}

   PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
NSLog(@" SAVEE %@ ",[[PFInstallation currentInstallation] objectId]);

    [currentInstallation save];


[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
return YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out how to fix it. I gave my tabbarcontroller an ID and then instantiated it, made it the rootviewcontroller and added the tabbar as subview

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *myVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TBController"];
self.window.rootViewController = myVC;//making a view to root view
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.window addSubview:myVC.tabBar];
```